# Word for seeing both sides of an argument

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, catch-phrases

This feeling can often be paralyzing in that you see valid points on either side; makes you not able to choose a side.

*Seeing* can also be *understanding*, *supporting*, *taking active part in*.

I'm looking for words that don't imply a "Janus"/traitor tone or the ambivalence tone, but the (property of the) process that *precedes* the paralyzing feeling and whose property is more reminiscent of walking a mile in another man's shoes.

Tag says single-word but multi-word adjectives can be okay. I usually shy away from just adding -y to make adjectives.

Sorry for the vague wording, I'll happily take suggestions on how to word this better. Thanks! :)

Usage:
"And above all, I hope *_*_ will become the preferred method to prepare for debate, to: ..."

It's a two-sided process of analysis involving attacks and reconciliations of attacks.

I was hoping for an established academic term for this, but perhaps none exist. I will embrace an inventive new word for this! This is a paper for peer review, so the meaning should be apparent to academics.

Comment: Are you by chance talking about [_analysis paralysis_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis)?

Comment: Could you provide a sentence with ____ where you want the desired word to appear?

Comment: As @StoneyB says, an example sentence will be useful. From what I understand, you want an adjectival equivalent of "seeing both sides of the coin", or alternatively, an equivalent of the word [dilemma](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dilemma) which does not carry connotations of "problematic". There are other related words such as quandary and predicament which are similar. There are also words like _impasse_, _stalemate_, and _deadlock_ which are ... paralytic in nature.

Comment: @StoneyB, added a sample sentence and clarification.

Comment: J.R., yes and no. The word *analysis* already has this "exploring sides" meaning built-in, but the method of analysis in my paper (as yet unnamed) has these qualities and yet hopes to show that it helps *avoid* indecision.

Comment: I do not understand why my comment is being just deleted without an explanation. That was an helpful contribution!

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández, it was not deleted by me. Please comment again :)

Comment: I've marked my own answer for deletion, as it does not reflect my new understanding of what you're looking for. How about *dialectic* (as a noun)?

Comment: It is a kind of dialectic, to be sure, but I will be speaking to philosophers who might have the term more definite in this context. Still, *this kind of dialectic* I think is the best match so far. Thank you and please suggest it as an answer. :) I wouldn't want to leave those who help me without a reward for doing so, in case I'm looking for a word that really isn't there.

Comment: I have done so. Thank you for your consideration. It's been fun!

Comment: I don't know if this might help or not, but when you wrote _It's a two-sided process of analysis involving attacks and reconciliations of attacks_, that kind of reminded of the minimax look-ahead algorithm in AI, or [Nash equilibrium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium) in game theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I understand what you want, 'dialectic' not only seems to answer the meaning you're after but also (since you say you're confronting an audience of philosophers) provides you additional opportunity to display your erudition by distinguishing, in highly technical detail, the Erlandssonian (Erlandssonic?) Dialectic from the Socratic and Hegelian.

Comment: Yes, *kind* of *process* is what I seek, ie. adjective of noun. Analysis possessing some of the qualities of the adjective has already been touched upon in comment. That might be the noun, but I have reached as far as a *kind* of *dialectic* from these helpful answers and comments. If I could replace "a kind of" with an adjective suggesting the nature of the active two-sided involvement as yet unnamed, that would come even closer.

Comment: Hm, you edited your answer to make my comment not make sense at all. I don't know that I appreciate that, but I do appreciate humor aimed at pretense ;) It's becoming increasingly difficult to know all the kinds of dialectic there have ever been, and while I might yet prefer the "cop-out" of *this kind of dialectic* to not get caught, I think that even if I've been preempted, this kind of dialectic deserves a name. It has many merits, not the least of which is sincere intent.

Comment: An excelent explanation, expressed in terms that can be understood without the need of lots of philosophical knowledge, but I would express my firmly conviction that 'dialectic' cannot be fully comprehended without an understanding of death and, for this scope, you should have posted another answer to avoid the death of the first @Henrik Erlandsson's comment!

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández I'm afraid the dialectic of death is an allusion that escapes me - I already named all the dialectics I'm familiar with (I regard the Marxist dialectic as a branch of the Hegelian), and I'm not even an amateur philosopher, much less a professional one. But I'm eager to be enlightened.

Comment: @Henrik Well, you wanted just one word. I agree that it wants a more specific and more meaningful name, but I'd probably have to read your paper to be able to offer a useful suggestion. 'Erlandssonian' is just a placeholder. . . It could be 'dialectic something' as well.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson I've run across the term 'rhetoricist' at [link](http://www.er.uqam.ca/nobel/philuqam/dept/textes/Rhetoricist_Creed1995.pdf) (see p.5, in particular) which since you seem to be aiming ultimately at persuasiveness rather than 'truth' might be applicable. "rhetoricist dialectic"?

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández Perhaps, referring to the narrative of custodianism, one could suggest the underlying fictitious nature of the fractious, meaningless, profanity and of the classical view of death, incumbent?

Comment: @Matt: This. The perfect analytic synthesis of structuralism and deconstructivism.

Comment: @Matt But in that way you reduce the Hegelian 'dialectic' to the phenomena of desire, struggle, labor and speech!

Comment: @MattЭллен I hope to never become a neo-classical deconstructivist philosopher. ;) StoneyB, no, you changed from the right track to the wrong one there, I think. Mark answers for deletion all you want, I'm marking yours as the answer, because in the end I went with, "...while my kind of dialectic might not..., it ...".

Comment: He asked for adjective. Dialectic is a noun or a verb. An adjective suggestion could be ‘conflicted’.

Comment: @ShelbyMooreIII OP's sample sentence calls for a noun (though it will accommodate an adjective).

Comment: @StoneyB I only took notice of the adjectives keyword tag. Indeed I see the sample sentence now.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to think of this as being ***objective***

> [**Objective**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/objective) *adj* : Uninfluenced by emotions or personal prejudices, fair

Comment: It's a process of getting your hands dirty and go with prejudices of the other side; use them to attack your own side and see by them how the other side would receive your attack. On a humorous note, *Schizophrenic* and *Bipolar* have been considered. It *is* a chore. ;)

Comment: @Henrik I think you need to be objective and understand where the prejudices come from, understand what's behind them and account for them when coming up with a solution and the only way to do that is to be objective.  If you adopt prejudices on either side you will, by definition, close your mind to other points of view.  I see though that you have revised your question so objectivity isn't quite the word you are looking for.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson- Based on your intended usage I might suggest: And above all, I hope *objective research on both sides of the argument* will become the preferred method to prepare for debate.

Answer (score 0):

Circa 1970, Alvin Toffler popularized the term *[information overload](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_overload)*, which wikipedia says is nicknamed *infobesity* and "refers to the difficulty a person can have understanding an issue and making decisions that can be caused by the presence of too much information."  I hadn't heard of the nickname before looking up information overload, and have some doubts you'd be understood if you said "I'm feeling infobese."  However, "I'm suffering information overload on this issue" should be clear enough.

Two sentences that might be related to your meaning: "This review has got me *[straddled](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/straddle)*", "At the moment I'm fence sitting."

*Edit:* Given your example sentence, words like *[evenhanded](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/evenhanded)*, *[unbiased](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unbiased)*, and *[open-minded](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/open-minded#English)* may be more relevant, along with separately-suggested *[objective](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/objective#Adjective), [nonpartisan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonpartisan#Adjective)*, and *[impartial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impartial)*.

Also consider *[balanced](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/balanced)*, which is applicable in its various senses "Total debits and credits are equal [eg] the books looked balanced"; "Being impartial, unprejudiced or fair"; "Being proportional or proportionate"; "Being equitable or evenhanded"; "To be unprejudiced, evenhanded, even-handed or unbiased".

Comment: As stated, it's not so much about the place where you end up (the fence) but how you got there. In my paper, it's a process by which to weed out "waste of time" arguments: the indefensible, the untenable, the irrelevant, and the equally valid.

Answer (score 0):

The term *broad-minded* is very similar to *open-minded* suggested elsewhere. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/broad-minded) defines it as

> tolerant of varied views

Some dictionaries, such as [Cambridge Dictionary of American English](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/broad-minded) define the term as

> willing to accept behavior or beliefs that are different from your own

A *broad-minded analysis* suggests being open to various positions, but may suggest that the analyzer already has a point of view.

One of the definitions of *bilateral* in the [American Heritage Dictionary](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/bilateral) is

> affecting or undertaken by two sides equally; binding on both parties: *a bilateral agreement; bilateral negotiations.*

[Websters New World College Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/bilateral) defines it as

> having or affecting two sides

Many dictionaries have a definition of

> having two sides

A *bilateral analysis* (or even *multi-lateral analysis*) may suggest your concept.

SUPPLEMENT BASED ON COMMENTS: The dichotomy *point-counterpoint* has been used to describe a back and forth dialog between opposing points of view. Perhaps a *point-counterpoint exercise (or analysis)* might serve.

Comment: There's multi-faceted also, which I earlier considered from a like thread here. Well, here the urge is for not only seeing and tolerating the other side but actively exploring the other side; (in all honesty temporarily) actively taking the other side in order to see how he would view your attacks, among other things. *Bilateral* describes a common thing, which in this case would be the topic of argument, which indeed has two sides. Counterpoint suggests *Contrapunctus* which would be a nice new term, but I must first make sure that what I offer has not been preempted.

Comment: I thought about multi-faceted, but was concerned that it suggested various characteistics of a problem, not necessarily contrary points of view. But, I suspect OP would welcome analyzers bringing a *multi-faceted* approach to the issues as well.

Answer (score -1):

*Nonpartisan* and *impartial* are related words, commonly used to mean that the person does not take sides but instead makes an independent judgment.

Comment: The goal with this unnamed process is not to make a judgment per se: more of an exploratory process of actively taking both sides. A way for a debater who has already taken sides to not just prepare attacks on the other side, but take the other side and attack his own, and to reconciliate your previously prepared attacks. I think of it as "killing your darlings" to find out if your darlings (your pet arguments) are successful attacks. *Non-partisan* suggests not taking sides. Bipartisan has been considered, but it has political connotations.

Comment: I noticed that these words do not provide a logical extension of the usual meaning that the people, particularly in literature, bring up in their multifaceted arguments.