# Word for acknowledging all sides to an argument?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word for explaining/acknowledging any other stances or opinions on a topic while still stating your own, and even using the other sides to support the validity of your own opinion? The closest I've gotten so far is "dialectic", but even that doesn't seem quite right. I'm writing an essay in which I compare the usage of this device in a collection of nonfiction articles. I need a literary term describing this that I can refer easily to in writing.

An example sentence would be

> After carefully reviewing the provided nonfiction texts, I have ranked the three that I believe exhibit the best usage of _______, or the act of acknowledging multiple stances on an issue rather than just the author’s stance.

The tag says single-word requests, but if you have an accurate multiple-word term for it then that's fine too.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage!  Please note that a description of how the word you are looking for is required, as is a sample sentence with an indication of where the word would go.   Without this, your question is likely to be closed as off-topic.  Also, you might want to [take the site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through [the help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: *Opposing viewpoint*.

Comment: You might have a better chance of getting a response to your question (and, more importantly right now, getting it reopened) if you would explain *why* words like “dialectic” and the others discussed at [Word for seeing both sides of an argument](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/78066/26083) don’t meet your needs.   For example, I was going to suggest “bipartisanship” (or “nonpartisanship”) until I saw that they were already mentioned under that other question.